# Unable to send newly updated events form filebeat to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk

````
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - C:\Office\Work\processed_fileChaser_2020-05-22_12_56.log

  close_eof: true
  close_inactive: 10s
  scan_frequency: 15s
  tail_files: true

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["XX.XXX.XXX.XX:5044"]


 ------------------------ logsatsh config -----------------------------------

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message" 
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["tags", "ecs", "log", "agent", "message", "input"]
  }
}
output {
  file {
    path => "C:/Softwares/logstash-7.5.2/output/dm_filechaser.json"
  }
}

Sample input:

{"fileName": "DM.YYYYMMDD.TXT", "country": "TW", "type": "TW ", "app_code": "DM", "upstream": "XXXX", "insertionTime": "2020-05-20T13:01:04+08:00"}
{"fileName": "TRANSACTION.YYYYMMDD.TXT", "country": "TW", "type": "TW", "app_code": "DM", "upstream": "XXXX", "insertionTime": "2020-05-22T13:01:04+08:00"} ```

Versions:
Logstash: 7.5.2
Filebeat: 7.5.2

filebeat unable to send new data and always sends same data to logstash from file beat.
Can you please help how to send newly updated data from log to logsatsh.

Filebeat logs:
````

2020-05-22T15:39:30.630+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:256   Failed to publish events caused by: read tcp 10.10.242.48:53400->10.10.242.48:5044: i/o timeout
2020-05-22T15:39:30.632+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:256   Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
2020-05-22T15:39:32.605+0530    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:121  Failed to publish events: client is not connected
2020-05-22T15:39:32.605+0530    INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://10.10.242.48:5044))
2020-05-22T15:39:32.606+0530    INFO    pipeline/output.go:105  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://10.10.242.48:5044)) established
2020-05-22T15:39:44.588+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":1203,"time":{"ms":32}},"total":{"ticks":1890,"time":{"ms":48},"value":1890},"user":{"ticks":687,"time":{"ms":16}}},"handles":{"open":280},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"970ad9cc-16a8-4bf1-85ed-4dd774f0df42","uptime":{"ms":61869}},"memstats":{"gc_next":11787664,"memory_alloc":8709864,"memory_total":16065440,"rss":2510848},"runtime":{"goroutines":26}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":2,"added":2},"harvester":{"closed":1,"open_files":0,"running":0,"started":1}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"events":{"batches":2,"failed":4,"total":4},"read":{"errors":1},"write":{"bytes":730}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":2,"filtered":2,"retry":6,"total":2}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":1}}}}}
2020-05-22T15:39:44.657+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:251    Harvester started for file: C:\Office\Work\processed_fileChaser_2020-05-22_12_56.log

Comment: As the logs says, you have no connection between the machine with the filebeat and the logstash. check your network connection between them.